# How to recognise an item selection/click in navigation drawer list instead of using its position in android?

Tags: android, fragment, android-custom-view, navigation-drawer

A'right so here I am making an app with a Navigation drawer list.
Now in general a method is provided to respond to each item selection/click in the list.
The method is--

```
 private void selectItem(int position) {

Fragment fragment = null;

switch (position) {
case 0:
    fragment = new CreateFragment();
    break;
case 1:
    fragment = new ReadFragment();
    break;
case 2:
    fragment = new HelpFragment();
    break;

default:
    break;
}
```

Now I want to respond to the item click in the drawer list according to something else rather than just its position such as its title or image id. By far, I've failed to achieve this...can someone help???

Right now I'm using the navigation list code from this website:
     [Android Custom Navigation Drawer](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function that calls SelectItem.

```
@Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
              long id) {
        SelectItem(position);

  }
```

All you need to do is write a new function and put it where SelectItem() is.  You can pass your new function the view, and lookup it's title.  Example:

```
    public void example(View v){

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.exampleId);
        String title = tv.getText().toString();

        //Do something with title.. 
    }
```